# How can use I use PHP as back-end for ionic framework?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, backend

Can anyone give an example of using php at the backend with Angular JS at the front-end in the Ionic Framework?

Comment: yes you can very well use php but if you are already working with a js based framework in the front end why not do the same for back en as well. You can use Node.js + Express.js or sails.js for object mapping with mysql database. it offers much better performance for real time scenarios and the learning cure is small and fast

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Of Course !**

Me and my partner just completed working on a IONIC App integrated with PHP as its backend.

Just like a regular Frontend-backend, requests and responses are in the form of JSON.

For getting started quickly, here is a sample code we built for ourselves :

**send.php**

```
<?php
// Prevent caching.
//header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

// The JSON standard MIME header.
//header('Content-type: application/json');          

$data = array(
    "username" => "one",
    "email" => "ifyoucanreadthis@yes.com",
    "age"  => 22
    );

// Send the data.
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**recieve.php**

```
<?php

 /*
   * Collect all Details from Angular HTTP Request.
   */
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $usr = $request->email;
    $pass = $request->pass;

    echo "<h1> Username is : " . $usr . "<br /> and password is : ". $pass."</h1>"; //this will go back under "data" of angular call.
    /*
     * You can use $email and $pass for further work. Such as Database calls.
    */    

?>
```

Hope this helps you !

**EDIT 1 :**

The benefits of using PDO is over-rated. Read more about it here : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

I am assuming that you know about basic code for connecting to a database (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

As far as Angular coding is concerned, you may find the following links useful (sorry I don't have the angular code on this machine) :

http://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/angular-post-request-php/

http://www.cleverweb.nl/javascript/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php/

http://serebrov.github.io/html/2013-05-24-angular-post-to-php.html

Comment: Yes .Actually I have developed a web application. And I have been developing android and ios app for the same. So I need to use the same database ie mysql with xampp. So my question was regarding this .

Comment: I would suggest you to go with `$http.jsonp` requests, cause **CORS** is a major issue when it comes to Cordova based apps. In that case you will need to add a `callback` parameter while sending a request to the PHP function and while getting back response from the same PHP. So you should try that out, if it won't work you can post your code and I can assist you with it.

Comment: Okie. Thank You Keval. I'll try .