# Backend as a service for ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I wanted to use an open source backend as a service, for my ionic app. Tried to find some but couldn't get any such open source.

Can anybody help me with the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop an IONIC App by using  `PHP` as its backend.I have created an ionic application by using Laravel as back end.

**It Just like a regular Frontend-backend, requests and responses are in the form of `JSON`.**

I got some idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665933/ionic-how-can-php-be-used-as-backend-for-ionic-framework/29666267#29666267) answer.

Adding backend functionality to a ionic mobile app is incredibly easy with `AngularJS`.Just like a regular Frontend-backend, requests and responses are in the form of JSON. For simple backend interactions, the $http module lets us do simple HTTP calls to an API end point.

For more complicated API interaction, especially when interacting with a `RESTful API`, ngResource provides a lot of abstractions over common API interactions.

When in doubt, $http can be used for small, one-off HTTP requests, and ngResource and the $resource service should be used for all API interactions that act on real data models.

If you need any help.Please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've developed several Ionic apps using Drupal as the backend. As Muhsin mentioned, it's just using requests and responses in the form of JSON.

Adding and modifying the responses within the Drupal CMS as well as managing the content has worked well for me, but I have a Drupal background too.

If you're not stuck on just open source, I would recommend [Parse](http://www.parse.com/) or [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). Both offer nice Free plans.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Backand](http://www.backand.com) if you haven't done so before.

Backand just released full Ionic-Backand integration.

You can read out more at -
http://blog.backand.com/the-ultimate-stack-for-mobile-apps-ionic-backand/