# How to use the login credentials with php in ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to authenticate the `user_name` and `password` field. the `user_name` and `password` field is stored in database with php. how to get the data from the server in ionic project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand that Ionic is only a frontend framework. That means you need a backend to storing/processing data, which can be PHP. You can see example usage of PHP as a backend API here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665933/how-can-php-be-used-as-backend-for-ionic-framework.

Comment: Yes I knew that. I am new in ionic thats why thats why i want to know how to use the php in my project and how to get the data form server and I have a link of php? how to authenticate user name and password?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service script that can send post data to PHP and receive a JSON response.

Post data should be sent as an object containing element name and values in the following format:

```js
var myObj = {username: 'username', password:'password'};
```

Below is a service example:

```js
yourApp.service('YourService', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        login: function (data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                promise = deferred.promise;

            $http({
                url: 'http://www.example.com/yourPHPScript.php',
                method: "POST",
                data: data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.error.code === "000") {
                        
                        deferred.resolve(response.data.appointments);
                    } else {

                        deferred.reject(response.data);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
              
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });

            promise.success = function (fn) {
                promise.then(fn);
                return promise;
            };
            promise.error = function (fn) {
                promise.then(null, fn);
                return promise;
            };
            return promise;
        }
        
 };
});
```

From your login controller you call the following code to use the service (make sure you add the name of the service to your controller declaration)

```js
YourService.login(loginData)
        .then(function (data) {
   
        // on success do sthg
        }, function (data) {
            //log in failed
   
            // show error msg
        });
```